# Sensible way to create instant of class

Tags: c#, .net

***I am confuse where to declare instant of class if it uses many where.***

Suppose I have a form named **Order** in which I am performing four task like ***Insert, Update and delete and filling order data*.**

Logic for those all four task is in separate class file say **FinalOrder.cs**

Here, In example **fo** is instant created of class named **FinalOrder** and different method are called from **FinalOder** into the **Order** form.


***Below is the code for referring:***

**First way:**

```
FinalOrder fo = new FinalOrder();

private void Order_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvOrder.DataSource = fo.FetchOrders();
}
private void btnNewOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fo.NewOrder();
}
private void btnUpdateOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fo.UpdateOrder();
}
private void btnDiscardOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fo.DiscardOrder();
}
```

**Second way:**

```
private void Order_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FinalOrder fo = new FinalOrder();
    dgvOrder.DataSource = fo.FetchOrders();
}
private void btnNewOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FinalOrder fo = new FinalOrder();
    fo.NewOrder();
}
private void btnUpdateOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FinalOrder fo = new FinalOrder();
    fo.UpdateOrder();
}
private void btnDiscardOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FinalOrder fo = new FinalOrder();
    fo.DiscardOrder();
}
```

**Third way:**

```
FinalOrder fo;
public Order()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fo = new FinalOrder();
}

private void Order_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    dgvOrder.DataSource = fo.FetchOrders();
}
private void btnNewOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    fo.NewOrder();
}
private void btnUpdateOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    fo.UpdateOrder();
}
private void btnDiscardOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    fo.DiscardOrder();
}
```

**Please, explain me which is good to use with keeping memory allocation in mind and Why?**

Answer (score 2):

The first and the third way are the same; both will instantiate `FinalOrder` when the `Form` instance is created.

And if there are many `insert` / `delete` / `update` operations in your application, then use either the first or the third way to prevent instantiating `FinalOrder` each time you're calling these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on the characteristics of both `FinalOrder` and the class it is created from. For example if the class it is created from can be access by multiple threads you probably do not want it as member variable unless `FinalOrder` is thread safe.

(In you example it looks like it is created on a web form and it would than be safe to have as a member variable.)

Also an operation in the `FinalOrder` object might change the state of the object (would have to see the implementation of the functions) and that may change how future operations work, and it would than not work the same way as recreating it before every usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "Order" form used for just one order. so if it is Second way is better. If you going to multiple insert/Update/Delete 1st or 3rd way better, because they used only one instance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Singleton pattern or you can share the Instance of the FinalOrder class by writing a property in the FinalOrder class which return the instance of the FinalOrder class. Thus you can avoid creating instance on the other class.

Answer (score 1):

If `FinalOrder` is a simple class that doesn't use any expensive resources then I'd go with the **Second Way** it keeps the object lifetime short and encapsulated in the function for simple reuse.

If `FinalOrder` uses Unmanaged Resources or an `IDisposable` then I'd go with a ..

**Fourth way**

```
class FinalOrder : IDisposible
{
    ...
}

private void OrderLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var fo = new FinalOrder(...))
    {
        dgvOrder.DataSource = fo.FetchOrders();
    }
}
```

If the instantiation of FinalOrder were very expensive, then I may consider a private member for a common `FinalOrder` instance but ideally I would avoid this.